# Problem using pair with accumulate

Tags: c++, stl, numeric

I am using a deque so I can generate rolling averages and variances for my data. I store n and n^2 as a pair in the deque and then use accumulate with my own operator+().

```
#include <deque>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::pair<T1,T2> operator+(const std::pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const std::pair<T1,T2>& rhs)
{
   return std::pair<T1,T2>(lhs.first + rhs.first, lhs.second + rhs.second);
}

namespace resource 
{
template <typename T>
class rollingStats
{
public:
   rollingStats(unsigned int n, const T& val):
      xs(n, std::pair<T,T>(val, val*val))
   {;}
   ~rollingStats()
   {;}

   T getMean(void) const
   {
      std::pair<T,T> sum = std::accumulate(xs.begin(), xs.end(), std::pair<T,T>((T)0,(T)0));
      return sum.first / xs.size();
   }

   T getVar(void) const
   {
      const unsigned int n = xs.size();

      std::pair<T,T> sum = std::accumulate(xs.begin(), xs.end(), std::pair<T, T > ((T)0,(T)0));

      return ((n * sum.second - sum.first*sum.first) / (n * n));
   }

   void addValue(const T& val)
   {
      xs.pop_front();
      xs.push_back(std::pair<T,T>(val,val*val) );
   }

   const std::deque<std::pair<T,T> >& getXs(void) const {return xs;}
private:
   std::deque<std::pair<T,T> > xs;
};
}
```

I get a compilation error using g++ 4.1.2 which I can't resolve.

```
  [ CC         ]  resource/UnitTest: rollingStats_Test.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_numeric.h: In function ‘_Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp) [with _InputIterator = std::_Deque_iterator<std::pair<float, float>, const std::pair<float, float>&, const std::pair<float, float>*>, _Tp = std::pair<float, float>]’:
../rollingStats.hpp:45:   instantiated from ‘T resource::rollingStats<T>::getMean() const [with T = float]’
rollingStats_Test.cpp:98:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_numeric.h:89: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘__init + __first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = std::pair<float, float>, _Ref = const std::pair<float, float>&, _Ptr = const std::pair<float, float>*]()’
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_bvector.h:267: note: candidates are: std::_Bit_iterator std::operator+(ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_iterator&)
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_bvector.h:353: note:                 std::_Bit_const_iterator std::operator+(ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_const_iterator&)
make: *** [rollingStats_Test.o] Error 1
```

What have I got wrong here? Do I need to add my own functor instead of relying on the STL alone?

thanks

Comment: May I suggest using the [`boost::accumulators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/accumulators.html) library ?

Comment: I *think* you should try putting the + operator for the pair into the std namespace; looks like you might be hitting the C++ namespace resolution rules.

Comment: I managed to make this compile first time: http://codepad.org/an0dUFgk.

Comment: @Oliver: except that you are technically not allowed to do this.

Comment: Full testcase [here](http://www.ideone.com/Lc9U7).

Comment: @Oliver: No; don't add things to the `std` namespace. (Your problem analysis appears to be accurate, though.)

Comment: @jkp: You never instantiated the functions that cause the issue.

Comment: (realized I was going to get jumped on for that after hitting post... :)

Comment: I can see three options: use the form of accumulate that takes a binary function, using an add_pair function you'd need to write (probably the simplest option); subclass std::pair and give it addition operators (feels dirty); add a new struct/class that either has a pair or just has the members you need, and use that instead of the pair (probably the most flexible option).

Comment: There is another option (ok, it's just a different version of Oliver Seiler's first option) - move your `operator +` to resource namespace, and pass it as a function parameter to `accumulate` : `std::pair<T,T> sum = std::accumulate(xs.begin(), xs.end(), std::pair<T,T>((T)0,(T)0), resource::operator+<T,T>);`

Comment: @a1ex07 actually, you don't need to make a new namespace, you could just resolve to global scope: `::operator+<T, T>` : `std::accumulate(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), std::pair<int, int>{0, 0}, ::operator+<int, int>);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::pair` doesn't have an `operator+`, and you haven't provided a way for `std::accumulate` to call your implementation of `operator+`.

I would wrap the functionality you provided in `operator+` in a functor...

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct pair_sum : public std::binary_function< std::pair<T1,T2>, std::pair<T1,T2>, std::pair<T1,T2> >
{
    std::pair<T1,T2> operator()(const std::pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const std::pair<T1,T2>& rhs)
    {
       return std::pair<T1,T2>(lhs.first + rhs.first, lhs.second + rhs.second);
    }
};
```

...and use that by calling the version of `std::accumulate` that takes 4 arguments:

```
std::pair<T,T> sum = std::accumulate(xs.begin(), xs.end(), std::make_pair((T)0,(T)0), pair_sum<T,T>());
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed. I had thought that I could just provide my own operator+ for pairs and that it would be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Oliver Seiler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207540/oliver-seiler)'s comment:

I can see three options: use the form of accumulate that takes a binary function, using an add_pair function you'd need to write (probably the simplest option); subclass std::pair and give it addition operators (feels dirty); add a new struct/class that either has a pair or just has the members you need, and use that instead of the pair (probably the most flexible option).

[*This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to edit to add corrections, samples, etc.*]

Answer (score 0):

You can get sum of pairs with help of [`boost::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/lambda.html):

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>

template<typename T>
void summarize()
{
  typedef std::pair<T, T> pt_t;
  std::deque<pt_t> xs;
  using namespace boost::lambda;

  // fill xs with useful stuff

  pt_t res = std::accumulate(
    xs.begin(), xs.end(), std::make_pair(T(),T()),
    bind( constructor<pt_t>(),
      bind( std::plus<T>(), bind(&pt_t::first,_1), bind(&pt_t::first,_2) ),
      bind( std::plus<T>(), bind(&pt_t::second,_1), bind(&pt_t::second,_2) )
    ) );
}
```